# Generate session ID in jmeter, blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Need to generate new `AuthorisationId/sessionID` for each user.
 How is it possible to create a new for each user in `jmeter?`
If I am using the `sessionID` by recording, it is showing the session expired after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should "generate" this `sessionID`, most probably you need to [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) it.

My expectation is that when you open login page or perform login the application responds with the `sessionID` either in [redirection URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) or in response body or in response [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

First of all try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), it might be the case it will be enough to resolve your issue.

If not, you will need to identify where this `sessionID` is coming from and use the suitable JMeter's [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the `sessionID` and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). Once done you should replace recorded hard-coded value with the JMeter Variable from the previous step.

Check out [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables/) article for more information, if you will experience problems - don't hesitate to ask new question, but this time provide more at least partial response showing where this sessionID comes from and how you pass it to the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate it. Just use postprocessor extractor-regular expression. Replace the hard-coded values with the variable.